# How to customize non_field_errors key using the NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY in Django REST framework setting?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the docs, it was mentioned:

> Each key in the dictionary will be the field name, and the values will be lists of strings of any error messages corresponding to that field. The non_field_errors key may also be present, and will list any general validation errors. The name of the non_field_errors key may be customized using the NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY REST framework setting.

How exactly do I do that? Can someone give me a code example of what it would look like in the settings.py file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `settings.py` you need this

```py
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'NON_FIELD_ERRORS_KEY': 'your_key_here',
}
```

All other Django REST framework settings also go inside this dict